# Django + Nginx: 502 Bad Gateway on registration

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, gunicorn

What is the difference in the way manage.py runserver serves up a django project compared to gunicorn.wsgi?

I am using nginx + gunicorn to serve my django project.  Everything seems to work fine, but when users try to register, they get a 502 Bad Gateway.  However, when I run the server off of the development manage.py runserver, the registration goes through fine.

So, what is the difference between manage.py runserver and gunicorn.wsgi and what can I do to make sure gunicorn is configured properly?

Please let me know if you need more details.  Thanks